# Utilizar la librería gensim.coherencemodel para evaluar la similitud de mis tópicos

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp

Estoy utilizando la librería de `gensim.coherencemodel` para evaluar la coherencia o similitud de mis palabras clave para definir temáticas.

De momento he implementado el modelo y lo he aplicado sobre un ejemplo sencillo pero obtengo un error que no sé exactamente a qué se refiere. No utilizo un modelo LDA, este es mi código:

```
# Create Dictionary
id2word = corpora.Dictionary(data_lemmatized)

# Create Corpus
texts = data_lemmatized

# Term Document Frequency
corpus = [id2word.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]

from gensim.models import CoherenceModel

topics = [
    ['printer', 'colorimetry', 'blue colour', 'coor science'],
    ['primary colour', 'natural colour',
     'food colouring', 'traditional primary colour']
]

cm = CoherenceModel(topics=topics, corpus=texts, texts=data_lemmatized,
                dictionary=id2word, coherence='u_mass')
coherence = cm.get_coherence()
```

Y el error que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/coherencemodel.py", line 445, in _ensure_elements_are_ids
    return np.array([self.dictionary.token2id[token] for token in topic])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/coherencemodel.py", line 445, in <listcomp>
    return np.array([self.dictionary.token2id[token] for token in topic])
KeyError: 'blue colour'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/hadri/Desktop/TOPIC COHERENCE/skipgram.py", line 133, in <module>
        dictionary=id2word, coherence='u_mass')
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/coherencemodel.py", line 212, in __init__
        self.topics = topics
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/coherencemodel.py", line 427, in topics
        topic_token_ids = self._ensure_elements_are_ids(topic)
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/coherencemodel.py", line 448, in _ensure_elements_are_ids
        return np.array([self.dictionary.token2id[token] for token in topic])
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/coherencemodel.py", line 448, in <listcomp>
        return np.array([self.dictionary.token2id[token] for token in topic])
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/coherencemodel.py", line 447, in <genexpr>
        topic = (self.dictionary.id2token[_id] for _id in topic)
    KeyError: 'printer'
```

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

## Explicación del error.

Primero tenemos que saber qué es un `KeyError`

El error lo que te quiere decir, es que el topic que estás buscando no se encuentra en tu diccionary de palabras, es decir *"printer"* no existe en tu diccionario y por tanto cuando intenta buscar en el diccionario de palabras dicha palabra, da un `KeyError`, puedo imitar este error de la siguiente forma:

```
diccionario = {"foo":512, "bar":1024}

diccionario["printer"]
```

**Salida:**

```
KeyError: 'printer'
```

## Solución

Lo que te está sucediendo, es que la palabra *"printer"* no se encuentra en tu **diccionario de Gensim**, y por tanto cuando la va a buscar te da ese error.

En lo `topics` **debes poner palabras que se encuentren en el diccionario**

Comment: Ya encontré el problema, y es que ese método sólo admite topics de 1 token. Tengo que ver ahora cómo poder pasarle topics de más de 1 token...